# How to split into 3 JSONs from single XML file using XSLT in Oxygen

Tags: css, json, xml, xslt

My Input XML is having Header, Content and Footer Part. Conversion from XML to JSON works well using XSLT. But I need the output as a three parts as header, Content and Footer:

My Input XML file is:

```
<header>
  <trackingSettings>
    <urlcode>W3333</urlcode>
    <apiurl>http://mlucenter.com/like/api</apiurl>
  </trackingSettings>
</header>
<mlu3_body>
  <columnsCount>2</columnsCount>
  <lineBackground>linear-gradient(to right, rgba(94, 172, 192, 0) 0%, c4cccf 50%, rgba(94, 172, 192, 0) 100%)</lineBackground>
</mlu3_body>
<footer>
  <buttons>
    <button/>
  </buttons>
  <banner/>
</footer>
```

My XSLT using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="xml" />

        <xsl:template match="*">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/> : <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="*" mode="ArrayElement">
            <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="Properties">
            <xsl:variable name="childName" select="name(*[1])"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not(*|@*)">"<xsl:value-of select="."/>"</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="count(*[name()=$childName]) > 1">{ "<xsl:value-of select="$childName"/>" :[<xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="ArrayElement"/>] }</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>{
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
                    }</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="@*">"<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : '<xsl:value-of select="."/>',
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here im using Saxon PE in the oxygen:

I want this XML converted to 3 JSON files named `header.json`, `content.json`(mlu3_body) and `footer.json` in the output.

Is this possible by using XSLT or do I want to keep all input files separately. Please provide some ideas.

Comment: Well if you have "Conversion from XML to JSON works well using XSLT" then please show that code. In general XSLT 2.0 and 3.0 as supported by oXygen with Saxon 9 can of course write several result documents using `xsl:result-document` https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#creating-result-trees.

Comment: Edited with XSLT, please look into this @Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the XSLT to

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

        <xsl:template match="*">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/> : <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="*" mode="ArrayElement">
            <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="Properties">
            <xsl:variable name="childName" select="name(*[1])"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not(*|@*)">"<xsl:value-of select="."/>"</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="count(*[name()=$childName]) > 1">{ "<xsl:value-of select="$childName"/>" :[<xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="ArrayElement"/>] }</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>{
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
                    }</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="@*">"<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : '<xsl:value-of select="."/>',
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="header">
           <xsl:result-document href="header.json">
             <xsl:next-match/>
           </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="mlu3_body">
           <xsl:result-document href="content.json">
             <xsl:next-match/>
           </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="footer">
           <xsl:result-document href="footer.json">
             <xsl:next-match/>
           </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and it should generate three result files for those three elements. You will have to edit your question and tell us exactly which result you want if the produced contents is not quite right yet. It is also not clear whether the snippet of XML you have shown is part of a larger document.

Comment: I need to change anything in the transformation scenarios of oxygen parameters output tab??

Comment: I don't see why you would need to change anything in oXygen.